# How to hook up Blender Python script with Arduino?

Tags: python

[image]

I am trying to make a hologram were a series of propellers spin and emit lights to give off the hologram. I was planning on making the lights come on when they are touching an object inside Blender. What I mean by this is on each "propeller" a strip of lights are on each blade and it simulates this in Blender with accelerometers in 3D space. I want to know how to hook Blender up with the Arduino online editor and be able for them to correspond and transmit messages and signals.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot 'hook Blender up with the Arduino online editor', however you can have a program running on the Arduino that would communicate with a Python script running in Blender over serial connection(USB). Have a look at [pyserial](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/). You might probably be interested in [application handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.app.handlers.html) in Blender as well.

Comment: these things all help me with checking blenders stats and CPU but I want to connect or "hook up" the python script with the Arduino online editor so they correspond

Comment: What do you mean by 'correspond'?

Comment: to function together. were im from its got a bit of a different meaning to the dictionary.

Comment: I am not asking for the meaning of the word. :D What functionality are you after specifically? How do you imagine this would work? Could you give some example of use for this kind of functioning together? I am trying to get a more specific idea of what you are after.